# How to change the order of grouped barplots?

Tags: r, plot, bar-chart, figure

How can I bring the barplots in the right order from very low to very high and anthropogenic? 
And how can I change the position of the legend?

[image]

This is my R-Code:

```
barplot(bartab, col=colors()[c(23, 89)], beside=TRUE, legend=rownames(bartab))
```

Comment: With `barplot` you can change the order of you groups in your data frame and that should change the order of the bars. In future try provide [reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just order your data in the first place. For a better control of legend position make it separately.

***Example***

```
df1 <- mtcars[grep("^Merc", rownames(mtcars)), c(1, 2)]
df1 <- df1[order(df1$mpg), ]  # this orders your data by "mpg", look into `?order`

# plot
barplot(t(df1), col=c("blue", "green"), border="white", font.axis=2,
        beside=TRUE, xlab="group", font.lab=2)
legend("topleft", legend=c("mpg", "cyl"), pch=15, col=c("blue", "green"))
```

[image]

***Note:***

There are other possible strings to specify legend position, as the documentation states:

> ```
> The location may also be specified by setting x to a single keyword from 
> the list "bottomright", "bottom", "bottomleft", "left",
> "topleft", "top", "topright", "right" and "center".
> ```

You can also specify exact coordinates, see `?legend`.